# Is it possible to create a button which when pressed it replaces an existing object on the screen to another object in Smartface App Studio?

Tags: smartface.io

Is it possible to create a button which when pressed it replaces an existing object on the screen to another object in Smartface App Studio?

I've tried using the Onshow event on the text however it wasn't successful.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to replace an existing object to another object. You should create objects and add to page both of them but visible property of an object should be false on start and then you can change visible of object when button is pressed.I create a simple example for you:

```
var btn = new SMF.UI.TextButton({
 top : "80%",
 left : "10%",
 onPressed : page1_btn_onPressed
});
Pages.Page1.add(btn);

var myImage = new SMF.UI.Image({
    top: "20%",
    left: "15%",
    height: "20%",
    width: "70%",
    image: "default.png",
    imageFillType: SMF.UI.ImageFillType.stretch,
    visible : true
});
Pages.Page1.add(myImage);

var myImage2 = new SMF.UI.Image({
    top: "20%",
    left: "15%",
    height: "20%",
    width: "70%",
    image: "icon.png",
    imageFillType: SMF.UI.ImageFillType.stretch,
    visible : false
});
Pages.Page1.add(myImage2);

function page1_btn_onPressed(e) {
  myImage.visible= false;
  myImage2.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: What is the event for the images

Comment: I didn't use any event for images.I wrote "visible" property of objects in the on Pressed event of textbutton

Comment: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Vzd5UwjvT4D-K7uUTrkPORxh62fTOuzO_7XhUfKfB7o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1W2LqI7jNvA1zdSo4uWdnFsL7EAB5tw1gSkFPDRskQqo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Smartface doesnt have labelfilltype property and label doesnt have image property.And also you dont have textbutton object.You should create a textbutton

Comment: if you don't have button you cannot use onPressed event of button. I updated code in my answer.You can see how you can use button and onPressed event.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a simple app which replaces an object Thankyou I really appreciate this