# RE:Create a button which when pressed it replaces an existing object on the screen to another object in Smartface App Studio?

Tags: smartface.io

After seeing @catherinelagoon's post I also having difficulty in quite understand how to replace an object using a button so is it possible to create a button which when pressed it replaces an existing object on the screen to another object in Smartface App Studio?

I tried using the answer provided in the post however I couldn't understand it much due to I'm a beginner in using Smartface App Studio and coding itself.

Thankyou and sorry for any inconvienience

Comment: My answer in the post, you firstly create a button and two images. One of images is invisible on start and after you click button, it makes visible this image and invisible other image.So, you can change images when button is pressed. I added these changing codes in onPress event of button.if I understand you wrong could you explain what you need? Did you try to run code in answer?

Comment: For some reason even when I just add an image it doesn't show when testing the app

Comment: Can you share your codes?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1OoD4_yxYtQ2F3VHTTU10mv8LZO5rgNStCxnBE5a3iJA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add some information from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723564/is-it-possible-to-create-a-button-which-when-pressed-it-replaces-an-existing-obj, so this Post makes sense even without the other one.

Answer (score 0):

After you create an image you should add it to a Page so it can show on that page. So here is a simple code for creating and showing an image on the page.

```
var image = new SMF.UI.Image({
        visible: false
    });
Pages.Page1.add(image);

function Page1_TextButton1_OnPressed(e) {
    image.visible = true;
}
```